# Translating 'do well in' into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

**How is 'do well in' translated into Latin**? For example

> I do well in learning (i.e. I excel in learning)?

I guess it will involve *[bene facio]* plus some form of *[disco, discere]*, but what word form does it take? A gerund, infinitive, ABL. supine, etc.? Or is it an entirely different construction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if there is a popular direct analogue for "do well" in Latin, but I do know that you could simply say "I learn well", disco bene

Comment: @healynr Yes, this is a great substitute... Somehow I just missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

*Proficere* means “to make progress, perform, advance.” For example, you can say:

> Magnum profeci in studiis Latinis.
> *I have made great progress in my Latin studies.*

(Note that *studia* is more general than the English “studies” suggests; it can also be translated as “efforts” or “endeavours.”)

If you aren't doing so well, you could say: *parum proficio* (I am making little progress), if you aren't makeing any headway: *nihil proficio*. Since your user name is “aliquid,” you may be interested to hear one can also say *aliquid proficere*, i.e. “to make some progress.”

But wait, that's not all. The idea of “making progress” can also be expressed by saying *progressum facere* (or *progressus facere* – plural) or indeed *habere*, e.g. [Cicero, Tusc. 1, 19 (44)](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/tusc4.shtml#44):

> Philosophiae denique ipsius principes numquam in suis studiis tantos progressus sine flagranti cupiditate facere potuissent.
> *Finally, the best philosophers could never have done so well in their efforts without a burning enthusiasm.*

Who ever said Latin is difficult?

You can also say *processus*, it works more or less the same way.